# Encode decimals to binary to minimize hamming distance

Tags: algorithm, matlab, encoding, distance

Does there exist such an algorithm where say I have a matrix of 16 digit decimals, say:

```
0.00174432867509199
0.00450598829140463
0.00748670829846162
0.00988124652720609
0.00430372595333872
0.0160831788674987
0.00951600302244763
```

I can encode them in binary in such a way to reflect the hamming distance on their decimal distance?

For example, say we encode the integer 4 and 3:

```
4 -> 0100
3 -> 0011
```

They have a hamming distance of 3. But their "step" in the decimal system is only 1.

My question is there any research/scheme/algorithm designed that designs an encoding system for realistic hamming distances for decimal numbers?

Matlab solutions if any, are preferred.

Comment: can you please elaborate..Take a simple 3-decimal and explain

Comment: So, if I had 0.01, 0.02 and 0.77 I'd want there to be less bit differences between 0.01 and 0.02 compared to say 0.01 and 0.77

Comment: Hi, I have added that tag. I put in Matlab because if there are solutions that matlab gives then I prefer that

Comment: You might be interested in *Gray codes*.  I'm not aware of any work to use them for encoding fractions, but I suppose you could start by multiplying all yours by `10^16`.

Comment: I'll look into them, thanks! The issue with multiplying by 10^16 is unfortunately the distance will be quite large between the numbers

Comment: For integers you can use a Gray code or alike (reflected binary code). Something similar may be used for floating numbers (mantissa in Gray code?). Ohoh, didn't saw @HighPerformanceMark answer...